# In SQL, how can I split the values in a bitmask total into a comma delimited string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a bitmask value stored as an int in sql. I'd like to turn that value into a comma separated list of the values contained in the bitmask value.

So, for example, the results might look like so:

```
id  name      bitMaskValue   values
----------------------------------------
1   Bob       5              1,4
2   Mary      13             1,4,8
3   Stan      11             1,2,8
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a sql statement?

This is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just an FYI, you're really abusing your RDBMS. Databases are meant to work *really well* with foreign keys. I hope you had some pretty specific requirements before you added a bitmask to your record, rather than correctly normalizing the data and using a typical junction table.

Comment: I completely agree with you @meagar. In my case, I have some legacy data (the bitMaskValue) that I'm just trying to normalize and push out to another source that takes comma delimited values. I thought it was an interesting puzzle and since I wasn't finding any sql only solutions via google or on SO, I wondered what good solutions people might have.

Comment: @meagar It may not be a good use of RDBMS, but even Microsoft uses a bitmask in its internal tables (i.e. ReportServer..Schedule). The question may not cover a best practice scenario, but a scenario that exists nonetheless. I found the question very relevant and the answers have helped me a great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @I integer = 2117

Declare @v varChar(32) = ''
Declare @Bit tinyInt = 0
while @I > 0 Begin
Set @v += case @I %2 WHen 1 Then str(@bit,2,1) + ',' else '' End 
Set @Bit += 1
Set @i /= 2
End
Select case  When len(@v) > 0 Then left(@v, len(@v) -1) else '' End
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a function for this and it worked well. I changed the output from `str(@bit,2,1)` to `str(power(2,@bit),2,1)` to match what I needed.

Comment: btw,  I totally agree with @meager's comment to your question.  This is not an appropriate/good use pf a database server...

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
SELECT id, name, bitMaskValue,
    SUBSTRING(
            CASE WHEN bitMaskValue & 1 = 1 THEN ',1' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN bitMaskValue & 2 = 2 THEN ',2' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN bitMaskValue & 4 = 4 THEN ',4' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN bitMaskValue & 8 = 8 THEN ',8' ELSE '' END
        , 2, 64) As [values]
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`CTE + XPATH way`:

```
set nocount on

declare @t as table(id int, name varchar(100), bitMaskValue int)

insert into @t(id, name, bitMaskValue) values(1,'Bob',5)
insert into @t(id, name, bitMaskValue) values(2,'Mary',13)
insert into @t(id, name, bitMaskValue) values(3,'Stan',11)

;with cte(num) as 
(
select 1 
union all
select num*2
from cte
)
select 
    id, 
    name,
    bitMaskValue,
    stuff((
        select cast((
        select isBitSet
        from
        (
            select top 31 num, 
                         case 
                            when bitMaskValue & num = num then ',' + cast(num as varchar(10)) 
                            else null 
                         end isBitSet
            from cte
        ) tmp
        where isBitSet is not null
        for xml path('')) as xml).value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)')
    ), 1, 1, '') bitSet
from @t
```