# Flattening T-SQL bitmask from enumeration table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to flatten a list of functions that are stored in a bitmask, and that are "explained" in an enumeration table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #enum([ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                   [Display] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
                   [DataValue] [int] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO [#enum] ([Display], [DataValue]) 
SELECT  'Function A', 1 
UNION SELECT 'Function B', 2 
UNION SELECT 'Function C', 4 
UNION SELECT 'Function D', 8 
UNION SELECT 'Function E', 16
UNION SELECT 'Function F', 32 
UNION SELECT 'Function G', 64;
```

My data table looks like this (obviously much simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE #people ([ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                      [PersonName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
                      [Functions] [int] NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO [#people] ([PersonName], [Functions]) 
SELECT'Ken Hurt', 8 
UNION SELECT 'Justin Case', 33 
UNION SELECT 'Bill Board', 73;
```

Now I would like to return a comma-separated list of functions when querying the #people table; result like this:

```
ID        Name          Functions
1         Ken Hurt      Function D
2         Justin Case   Function A, Function F
3         Bill Board    Function A, Function D, Function G
```

I've been looking at Dynamic SQL, `PIVOT`, `STUFF()` and `FOR XML PATH()` for quite some time now but I'm apparently too stupid to digest the concept in its beauty. Could you please help? Going through the list with WHILE or even worse Cursors seems like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Thanks!

Comment: Why have you opted to violate first normal form for this many to many relationship?

Comment: Wasn't me - the C# developers love to work with bitmasks apparently

Comment: Return a normalized result set and let the C# developers format it the way they want.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Sorry for that, I've edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct way:**

Schema is "broken". Normalize it.

---

**Workaround:**

There is no need for `WHILE/CURSOR/PIVOT/Dynamic-SQL`. Simple bitwise operation will do the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM #people p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + e.Display
                          FROM #enum e
                          WHERE p.Functions & DataValue = DataValue
                          ORDER BY e.DataValue
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
           ) AS sub(result);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/GHQ86842)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ PersonName  ║ Functions ║              result              ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Bill Board  ║        73 ║ Function A,Function D,Function G ║
║  2 ║ Justin Case ║        33 ║ Function A,Function F            ║
║  3 ║ Ken Hurt    ║         8 ║ Function D                       ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: This looks like the beautiful solution that I was to stupid to get to! I'll test it on the live data and accept then. Thanks!

Comment: a different solution that seems way simpler to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16404032/749626

Answer (score 1):

I solved my very similar problem like this:

```
  SELECT p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation,
    SUBSTRING(
            CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,0) = POWER(2,0) THEN ', Two Parent Family' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,1) = POWER(2,1) THEN ', One Parent Family' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,2) = POWER(2,2) THEN ', Foster' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,3) = POWER(2,3) THEN ', Step Home' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,4) = POWER(2,4) THEN ', Institution' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,5) = POWER(2,5) THEN ', Living On Own' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,6) = POWER(2,6) THEN ', Homeless' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,7) = POWER(2,7) THEN ', Other' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,8) = POWER(2,8) THEN ', Siblings' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,9) = POWER(2,9) THEN ', Relatives' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,10) = POWER(2,10) THEN ', Spouse' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,11) = POWER(2,11) THEN ', Non-Marital Partner Childs Parent' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,12) = POWER(2,12) THEN ', Non-Marital Partner not Childs Parent' ELSE '' END
          + CASE WHEN p.nmbCurrentLivingSituation & POWER(2,13) = POWER(2,13) THEN ', Unknown' ELSE '' END
        , 3, 150) As [values]
    FROM tblParticipant p
```

Results look like this:

```
nmbCurrentLivingSituation   values
1       Two Parent Family
2       One Parent Family
NULL
0
770     One Parent Family, Siblings, Relatives
```

And I owe thanks to this post:
[In SQL, how can I split the values in a bitmask total into a comma delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403872/in-sql-how-can-i-split-the-values-in-a-bitmask-total-into-a-comma-delimited-str/16404032#16404032)