# Display Column value according to need in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

if i have a column in which ten digit values occurs like `Column A = 11111000` so how to show this value in sql like (`List,Add,Edit,Delete,Export`) in sql.

there is a condition means if first position have 1 then it show List, If second Position have 1 it show Add, third position have 1 then Edit, fourth position have 1 then Delete, fifth position have 1 then Export.

Comment: What you have is a bitmask and you need to parse it. Try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16403872/1324345) for a number of ways to handle it.

Comment: What is the type of the column?  Integer or string?

Comment: Column A is Sql_variant type

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a string, you can do:

```
select stuff( ((case when substring(a, 1, 1) = 1 then ',List' else '' end) +
               (case when substring(a, 2, 1) = 1 then ',Add' else '' end) +
               . . .
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

The logic is similar for bitwise operators:

```
select stuff( ((case when a & 2^9 then ',List' else '' end) +
               (case when 2 & 2^8 then ',Add' else '' end) +
               . . .
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Substring function can help you to identify these values

```
select 
    id, ColumnA,
    case when substring(ColumnA,1,1) = '1' then 'X' end as List,
    case when substring(ColumnA,2,1) = '1' then 'X' end as [Add],
    case when substring(ColumnA,3,1) = '1' then 'X' end as Edit,
    case when substring(ColumnA,4,1) = '1' then 'X' end as [Delete],
    case when substring(ColumnA,5,1) = '1' then 'X' end as [Export]
from Table1
```

[image]

I update the query according to comment

```
select 
    id, ColumnA,
    stuff(
    case when substring(ColumnA,1,1) = '1' then ',List' else '' end +
    case when substring(ColumnA,2,1) = '1' then ',Add' else '' end +
    case when substring(ColumnA,3,1) = '1' then ',Edit' else '' end +
    case when substring(ColumnA,4,1) = '1' then ',Delete' else '' end +
    case when substring(ColumnA,5,1) = '1' then ',Export' else '' end
    ,1,1,''
    )
from Table1
```

[image]

Comment: actually desired output like this (List,Add,Edit,Delete,Export)

Comment: Hi @PAL, I added a second query, please check it